# Why is org-babel not recognizing C code?

Tags: c, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am running version 7.01 of org-mode on emacs version 24 with Ubuntu 12.04 and I am unable to use C source blocks.  The default emacs-lisp language works fine, though.

Typing C-c ' does not create a separate buffer for entering C-code but instead states, ``No such language mode:C-mode'' in the minibuffer.

Typing C-c C-c will only produce the following message,
``Before first headline at position 15 in buffer src.org,'' for any choice of code in the body of the block.  For example,

```
 #+begin_src C
 #include <stdio.h>
 printf("hello");
 #+end_src
```

My current value of org-mode-load-languages is ((emacs-lisp . t) (C . t)).
Is there another variable to configure that I'm missing?

All of the documentation I've read on using code blocks only refers to changing the org-mode-load-languages variable to start using supported languages.  Any thoughts or suggestions on where the problem is would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You example works fine for me with org-mode 7.8.02. Does changing the capital C to lower-case help?

Comment: No, using lower case c produces this message, ``No org-babel-execute function for c!''.  org-babel-execute is used in ob.el.

Comment: I upgraded to version 7.8.02 and C-c ' now works as expected; however, C-c C-c will now print the #+results header with no results from the code, a new empty buffer opens *Org-Babel-Error_output, and the error is, Babel evaluation exited with code 5.  Does anyone know what code 5 is?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same issue 9 years later.

Make sure you've made the language available to Babel:

```lisp
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '(
     (C . t)  ; provide C, C++, and D
     ))
```

The name of the Babel source file for C-like languages is `ob-C.el`. You'll also need the to be compiler on your PATH.

See the docs for more information: https://www.orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html